# Is every matrix in $F[x]^{n\times n}$ is row-equivalent to an upper-triangular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve this problem, but I don't have any idea of what I should do..

> True or false? Every matrix in $F[x]^{n\times n}$ is row-equivalent to an upper-triangular matrix.

This is a question in the section 7.4 of the book of linear algebra of Hoffman-Kunze.

Comment: what is row equivalence??? you tried for $2\times 2$ matrix?

Comment: Can you see if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 1):

See carefully the proof of Theorem 6. Do the same thing, then we get an upper triangular matrix which is row-equivalent to the original matrix.
(Only different thing is that we do not assume (ii), so the entries of the main diagonal may not be 1.)

Answer (score 0):

What the question is asking you is if it is possible to, using row operations, reduce any matrix in $F[x]^{n\times n}$ to an upper triangular matrix. You need to either prove that it is always possible, or come up with a counter example.

Comment: Can you see if a have a correct answer please?